# Cleos wallet creation doesn't work

Tags: cleos

I have a single node testnet running, but cleos wallet create returns an error. [image]

Has anybody else gotten this, and fixed it? I've tried reinstalling all of eosio, and all of the tests (36/36) pass.

Comment: Note: it still worked with 1.0.8, but failed with 1.0.10.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this flag when running nodeos: `--http-validate-host=false` or add it to your `config.ini`, and don't forget to restart `keosd`